# Can I specify packages to be upgraded?

Tags: command-line, upgrade, apt

Can I choose which packages I want to upgrade with apt?

Using `apt-get upgrade` upgrades **all** packages, not just some of them.

Using `apt-get install package` doesn't upgrade some by me required packages which are related to the specified package.

**Example:** When I type `sudo apt-get install firefox`, packages like `firefox-locale-en` still using previous package version.

Comment: Why do you want only upgrade some specified packages?

Comment: @obysr If there are no updates to any dependency, then the installed version will be kept when updating the main package. In fact, the new version of the package has that "old" version of a dependency as its own dependency.

Comment: @BuZZ-dEE cause my connection has limited quota, so i just download that i think they're important.

Comment: @carnendil it means firefox-locale-en is not firefox's depencies? how does canonical manage its product?

Comment: @obysr `firefox` doesn't depend on `firefox-locale-en`. You can see it with: `apt-cache depends firefox`.

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have old versions of the packages `foo` and `bar`, you can use `apt-get install foo bar`, which will install the latest versions of selected packages `foo` and `bar`, resulting in an upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

If there are specific packages that you don't want upgraded, you can lock them to the current version.  There are instructions here: [How to prevent updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18654/how-to-prevent-updating-of-a-specific-package)

Then you can use `apt-get upgrade` to update the rest.